# Spark-Java static files location issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea, template-engine, static-files, spark-java

I called staticfiles.location("/public") from my main method, before any other spark method, and for some reason only one of the directories under the static files directory is working with the shortened path. File in my templates directory "public/templates" have to be called with "/public/templates/foo.vtl", however files in my CSS directory, "public/css" can be called with "/css/bar.css"

One thing I could note is that the abbreviated path for the css file was originally in my .java file but is now in one of my template files. It still works from the template file. Why is my templates folder not recognized under my public folder but my css folder is?

I'm using IntelliJ idea for this project.

Here's my code, although it's nearly identical to the layout tutorial code on the Spark website. I had a similar issue with Netbeans a few weeks ago, and switching IDE's seemed to resolve the problem. Is this perhaps an issue with my IDE not updating a resources file of some sort? I'm stumped! It's not a big issue but I'd rather know why it doesn't work rather than go on being blissfully ignorant.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    staticFiles.location("/public");
    String layout = "public/templates/layout.vtl";
    //secure("public/keystore.jks", "password", null, null);

    get("/", (req, res) -> {
        HashMap model = new HashMap();
        model.put("template", "public/templates/main.vtl");
        return new ModelAndView(model, layout);
    }, new VelocityTemplateEngine());

    get("/page2", (req, res) -> {
        HashMap model = new HashMap();
        model.put("template", "public/templates/main2.vtl");
        return new ModelAndView(model, layout);
    }, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

Here is an image of my folder structure, in case that mess of text above didn't make much sense:

[image]

Edit: Per request, the following is the content of my target directory.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you to downgrade to spark 2.3 and try again. Please provide me feedback.

Comment: @Laercio I downgraded to spark 2.3 and changed the staticFiles.location() line to staticFileLocation() per the 2.3 documentation, however I still receive the same 500 error when attempting to load a template with the shortened path instead of the full path from the resources folder.

Comment: TheFunk, Could you please show what you have under target directory?

Comment: @Andrew Post updated :)

Comment: TheFunk,you should use "templates/main.vtl" instead "public/templates/main.vtl"(in all cases). Please try and write if it works.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use **"templates/"** instead **"public/templates/"**.

Because location that you specify interpreted as **"public/public/templates"** and it doesn't exist under your target directory.

When you create **ModelAndView(model,templatePath)** you specifying wrong value from layout variable("public/templates/layout.vtl"). You have to set path for each template. Like in example below.

[image]

Comment: That's actually the exact opposite of my issue I think. I'm attempting to set my static file location however the system does not recognize /templates as a valid path. Instead it ONLY recognizes /public/templates as a valid path.

Interestingly though, the system recognizes /css as a valid path and both that folder and the templates folder are located under public.

Comment: TheFunk, Could you please try run your project in eclipse IDE. And if you have this code on github send me link I'll try it on IDEA.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew

I appreciate the help. I'm really stumped here. I wouldn't have asked if I hadn't at least tried a couple things first. I had this same issue in Netbeans a few weeks ago, then switched to IDEA and the problem was seemingly resolved. My code is available [here](https://codeshare.io/ww2Yx)

Comment: Thank you but I think I need to explain my issue a little better. The code I provided above should not run, as you know. The path should point to /public/public/templates/whatever.vtl as you've said. The issue I'm having is that the code above is actually running, compiling, and doing exactly what I want. The system is ignoring my staticFileLocation("/public") line. What would make it do this?

Comment: TheFunk, So you problem that after running application during development your files didn't update?

Comment: I think so. Basically the line that says "staticFileLocation" is being ignored. If I don't specify "/public/templates" every time, then the code will not run.

Comment: If you specify "staticFileLocation" it's mean that files witch located in this folder is available for View engines.

Comment: Could you please specify what you expected when you run code?Because your issue is not clear for me.

Comment: Yes, and folders. My css folder is located under public and is referenced from my combined templates. This folder's path is responding to the static file location. The templates folder however, also located under public, is not responding to the static file location.

Comment: I can reference CSS like this "css/menubar.css" however I can only reference templates like this "public/templates/main.vtl"

Comment: When you specify path you mean IDE or path in browser?

Comment: "The system is ignoring my staticFileLocation("/public") line" You mean when you change files you don't see changes in browser?

Comment: I recreated the project in another IDE (Netbeans) and have the same issue.

Comment: Could you please step by step write what you doing and what you expect as result?

Comment: Changing the staticfiles location breaks my css implementation. From this we can infer that files stored in the templates folder are reacting to what the staticfiles location is set to. Changing staticfiles has no impact on my java file however, where my templates are defined (as shown in the image above). It doesn't matter what my static files location is set to, the rest of that Java file above, ignores the preface of "/public" or whatever I may set the path to.

Comment: I should add, the css file is referenced from one of the templates with "css/menubar.css" hence why I know that changing the staticfiles location affects paths specified in files located in the templates subdirectory.

Comment: So I guess the real question is, why doesn't changing the staticfilelocation effect the rest of my java file?

Comment: Excitingly, I think I'm onto something! I think the issue may have something to do with velocity's classpath resource loader. I have a feeling it is searching in my src/main/java folder for my templates folder.